# How does a browser handle cookie with no path and no domain

Tags: http, url, cookies

I have googled this a lot now and have found conflicting answers. So my question is: how does a browser handle an HTTP cookie that has no `domain` and no `path` attributes?

For example this response from server:

```
200 OK https://example.com/a/b (6047ms) 
Set-Cookie: x-my-cookie=1.0; Max-Age=86400000; Expires=Sun, 05-Jan-2020    08:30:25 GMT
```

Should the cookie be included when making requests to `https://m.example.com/a/b`?

What about `https://example.com/zzzz`?

And `https://example.com/a`?

And `https://example.com/a/b/c`?

And `https://example.com`?

Comment: Be careful with the accepted answer - it's incorrect in regards to one scenario, which I've detailed in a new answer. (Other than that I believe it's all good.)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For `Set-Cookie` without `domain` attribute, the cookie's domain value is "the origin server". According to [RFC6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265):

> Unless the cookie's attributes indicate otherwise, the cookie is
> returned only to the origin server (and not, for example, to any
> subdomains)...If the server omits the Domain attribute, the user
> agent will return the cookie only to the origin server.

With the following exception:

> WARNING: Some existing user agents treat an absent Domain attribute as if the Domain attribute were present and contained the current host name.  For example, if example.com returns a Set-Cookie header without a Domain attribute, these user agents will erroneously send the cookie to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) as well.

Maybe that's why you found conflicting answers.

---

For `Set-Cookie` without `path` attribute, [RFC6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) states that:

> If the server omits the Path attribute, the user agent will use the "directory" of the request-uri's path component as the default value.

---

For your example, the answer would be:

**Should the cookie be included when making requests to https://m.example.com/a/b?**

No. Because `m.example.com` is not the origin server (`example.com`).

**What about https://example.com/zzzz?**

No. Because `/zzz` is not under "directory" `/a/b`.

**And https://example.com/a?**

No. Because `/a` is not under "directory" `/a/b`.

**And https://example.com/a/b/c?**

Yes. Because `/a/b/c` IS under "directory" `/a/b`.

**And https://example.com?**

No. Because `/` is not under "directory" `/a/b`.

Comment: And what about http requests? Does the cookie get included when making a request to [http://example.com/a/b/](http://example.com/a/b/)?

Comment: @DerDerrr That depends on whether `Secure` directive is set with the cookie. If `Secure` is set, the cookie won't be included in insecure HTTP request. Please refer to "Secure and HttpOnly cookies" on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies for more information.

Comment: @shaochuancs re the 3rd case: "No. Because `/a` is not under "directory" `/a/b`." I believe that is incorrect. [Section 5.1.4](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265#section-5.1.4), step 4 of the default-path algorithm states: "Output the characters of the uri-path from the first character up to, but not including, the right-most %x2F ("/")." In this case, there's no trailing "/" in the path, the right-most "/" is _before_ the `b`, so isn't the default path `/a` and hence this would be a "yes"?

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is incorrect in regards to one scenario:

> **And https://example.com/a?**
>
> No. Because `/a` is not under "directory" `/a/b`.

If you only care about Internet Explorer, that's true. If you care about the standard and browsers that comply with it, it isn't.

RFC 6265 provides the following [algorithm](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.1.4) for computing the default cookie path to use when a `Path` attribute is not present:

> The user agent MUST use an algorithm equivalent to the following
> algorithm to compute the default-path of a cookie:
>
> 1. Let uri-path be the path portion of the request-uri if such a
>    portion exists (and empty otherwise).  For example, if the
>    request-uri contains just a path (and optional query string),
>    then the uri-path is that path (without the %x3F ("?") character
>    or query string), and if the request-uri contains a full
>    absoluteURI, the uri-path is the path component of that URI.
> 2. If the uri-path is empty or if the first character of the uri-
>    path is not a %x2F ("/") character, output %x2F ("/") and skip
>    the remaining steps.
> 3. If the uri-path contains no more than one %x2F ("/") character,
>    output %x2F ("/") and skip the remaining step.
> 4. **Output the characters of the uri-path from the first character up
>    to, but not including, the right-most %x2F ("/").**

I've highlighted #4 becuase that's the part that matters. For a cookie set at uri-path `/a/b`, the "right-most" `/` is the one before the `b`. The algorithm says to stop there, hence the default cookie path is `/a` and therefore the cookie *should* get sent to `https://example.com/a`.

But as most web developers know, "should" is one thing and "does" is something else. So I wrote a small web app to test this exact scenario: **Will a cookie without an explicit Path attribute that is set at `/a/b` be sent in requests to `/a`?** Here's my findings (latest browser versions, Windows 10):

Chrome - yes

Firefox - yes

Edge - yes

Internet Explorer - no

Comment: I'm seeing this exact behaviour on Firefox. I set a cookie in a `/auth/facebook/callback` response, and in inspector the cookie path was `/auth/facebook`. My conclusion is that one should always set the cookie path to `/`.

Comment: @Todd Don't you think the RFC guys should update point 4 ? It seems they still expect to be of type `directory1/directory2/resource`. Thats the only reason in my opinion why they want to skip the last part which they expect will be resource. Unfortunately, this is not the case now days.