# What is the default cookie path of a cookie set at path /a/b/c?

Tags: http, cookies

RFC 6265 provides the following [algorithm](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.1.4) for computing the default path that a cookie should be applicable to in cases where a `Path` attribute is not present:

> The user agent MUST use an algorithm equivalent to the following
> algorithm to compute the default-path of a cookie:
>
> 1. Let uri-path be the path portion of the request-uri if such a
>    portion exists (and empty otherwise).  For example, if the
>    request-uri contains just a path (and optional query string),
>    then the uri-path is that path (without the %x3F ("?") character
>    or query string), and if the request-uri contains a full
>    absoluteURI, the uri-path is the path component of that URI.
> 2. If the uri-path is empty or if the first character of the uri-
>    path is not a %x2F ("/") character, output %x2F ("/") and skip
>    the remaining steps.
> 3. If the uri-path contains no more than one %x2F ("/") character,
>    output %x2F ("/") and skip the remaining step.
> 4. Output the characters of the uri-path from the first character up
>    to, but not including, the right-most %x2F ("/").

Let's take the example of receiving a `Set-Cookie` header with no `Path` attribute from `https://example.com/a/b/c`. In this case, `uri-path` is `/a/b/c`. There is no trailing slash, and therefore, if I'm interpreting the spec correctly, isn't the "right-most" slash is the one before `c`, and therefore the `cookie-path` is `/a/b`?

Another way of asking is, if a modern, spec-compliant browser received a cookie with no `Path` attribute (or any attributes besides `name=value` for that matter) from `https://example.com/a/b/c`, should that cookie be sent in a subsequent request to `https://example.com/a/b`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is no trailing slash, and therefore, if I'm interpreting the spec correctly, isn't the "right-most" slash is the one before c, and therefore the cookie-path is a/b?

Almost. From 1, `uri-path` would be `/a/b/c`. 2 and 3 don't apply. From 4, the output would be `/a/b`, with the leading `/` included.

> Another way of asking is, if a modern, spec-compliant browser received a cookie

If you mean *actual* browsers, this isn't *exactly* the same question; have you found an interpretation that differs?

There is still divergence from the spec, and a resource like [the web-platform-tests dashboard for `cookies/path`](https://wpt.fyi/results/cookies/path?label=master&label=experimental&aligned) may be a better resource to confirm modern browser behaviour.

However, to answer in terms of the spec:

> received a cookie with no Path attribute
> ...
> from https://example.com/a/b/c, should that cookie be sent in a subsequent request to https://example.com/a/b?

Yes, because the algorithm in 5.1.4 means the `default-path` of the cookie is `/a/b`, and this path-matches `/a/b` because

> The cookie-path and the request-path are identical.

Comment: Thanks! Just a little background. I have a fairly popular [HTTP library](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl). It's got some new features around cookies out in a prerelease. A couple months ago I commented in [this popular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43336097/62600) that I suspected he got part of it wrong. Didn't hear back, assumed I misinterpreted the spec, implemented per his answer, and now I have [this bug](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/560) making me rethink it all!

Comment: It all comes down to whether "right-most /" implies it's necessarily at the _end_ of the string. That's not how I interpret it, and good to find someone who concurs.